# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer while reading YAML in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have the following defined in a module in my Rails application:

```
module Selecting
  module Execution
    class ExecuteSpecific

      def self.perform!
        input = Data::FetchData.new.perform_action(param1, params2)
```

To make the code more general I want to remove the specific methodcall from the function and mode it to a YAML file as such:

```
:Newname:
  - example: 'Data::FetchData.new.perform_action(param1, params2)'
```

and refactor the above to ("name" should be passed as a symbol):

```
module Selecting
  module Execution
    class ExecuteSpecific

      def self.perform! name

        new = YAML.load_file('path/to/file.yml')[name]
        input = new[:example]
```

This return a

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is saying you are using a symbol where it expects an integer.  The only place you are doing that is where you call `new[:example]`.  `Yaml.load_file` returns array of strings and not symbols, so if you access your yaml loaded document using string index instead of symbol that should solve the problem.

Eg. `input = new['example']`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But if it returns 'Data::FetchData.new.perform_action(param1, params2)' as a string it's not going to be executed?